# Docker vs. Rocket in development

Tags: docker, containers, rocket

Why should I consider using Rocket instead of Docker in our development pipeline. We would like to use docker to create testable containers, but now there is Rocket which pretends to know the same. If we would like to start containerization should we seriously consider Rocket as it seems it is still pretty new?

There is not much information about Rocket, so I'm no clear where it stays now in 2015.

UPDATE: from https://coreos.com/blog/app-container-and-the-open-container-project/

> As we participate in OCP, our primary goals are as follows:
>
> - Users should be able to package their application once and have it work with any container runtime (like Docker, rkt, Kurma, or Jetpack)
> - The standard should fulfill the requirements of the most rigorous security and production environments
> - The standard should be vendor neutral and developed in the open

Comment: Peace has broken out between Docker and Rocket, leading to the establishment of the Open container initiative, https://www.opencontainers.org/  I anticipate that both projects will eventually settle on this common standard.

Comment: Does it mean they are forming common container layout? Then if I'm getting it right, they will be able to run either under Docker or in Rocket? Are they really able to settle on some common used standard. That will be really great. And I see it is really hot news.

Comment: http://venturebeat.com/2015/06/22/docker-and-coreos-unite-to-start-the-open-container-project-and-standardize-runtime-image-format/

Comment: AFAIK there was always peace between docker and rocket. Docker encouraged and fostered openContainers by donating their spec. I believe they have every intention of being as open and standards-compliant as they can.

Comment: Now is 2020 and we have https://podman.io/ and forgot about rocket )) Docker is still a thing though.

Answer (score 2):

Rocket is officially dead: https://github.com/rkt/rkt/issues/4024

After acquisition by Red Hot new owner concentrates efforts on https://podman.io/

`podman` provides rootless containers. Something that Docker strove to get for a long time (according to the below comment, they finally managed).

Comment: "Something that Docker strove to get but hadn't." is wrong.
Both Docker and Podman gained support for rootless almost simultaneously soon after BuildKit and containerd gained support for it, though Podman saw an official release  with rootless earlier than Docker (so people still misunderstand that it is specific to Podman)

Answer (score 1):

As with most competitors both have their advantage and disandvantages.

Docker hub offers a public registry where docker images can be pushed and pulled with ease.

There is also now a free registry offered by GitLab! Its really good.

A core issue at the moment is security. Docker now scan their images for security flaws and report on the security status of each image.

With rocket image signatures are cross checked with the signature of the publisher to see if they have been tampered with. This affords a degree of confidence.

For a fuller discussion on security see https://bobcares.com/blog/docker-vs-rkt-rocket/

With regards standards, it seems that OCI (Open Container Initiative) has been adopted by the big players and will pave the way forward for containerisation standatisation.